# Data loading in Azure DataWarehouse _Solution required

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I would like to storing the data in the DWH in a consistent matter. Every week I need to load data in AzureDW from on-Prem SQLDB.
The thing is that I have primary key in a table which I get every week. The example of table

[image]

I want to design in such a way that all 4 records gets stored in DW.

Shall I use surrogate key or is there some other better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is staged source data I wouldn't add a surrogate key, typically you only create surrogate keys in your dimensional model.

If your data volume is growing by semi-exponentially every time the process is run (unlikely) I would process as a CTAS, otherwise I would do a
INSERT INTO dbo.table
SELECT *, SYSUTCDATETIME() AS RECORD_INSERT_DATE FROM dbo.table_external_table

So you would just insert all incoming data and add a timestamp for the insert date. Your NK and timestamp become your unique key on the table.

If your requirements involve easily returning the current version of the record you could use a typeII SCD pattern to set a end date for the most recent version of the record and start date + active flag for the new version of the record.